# Maven Server Authentication Function

Tags: maven, authentication, server

I am going to develop a maven auth server. Our data are stored in a cloud and I got a Spring endpoint to serve the data. Now I am wondering how maven talks.

Is there any way to get a working auth?

Thanks for each contribution. Code following in the discussion...

Comment: What do you mean by `Maven Auth Server` ? I think you mean that you are developing an App which has an Auth server?

Comment: No. I wanna fake a repo server an its auth. The client should think that this is a real maven server. We wanna check the username and password and then we can check wheather we can handle the artifact or not.

Comment: By `real maven server` you are talking about a repository manager?

Comment: yes I am. I think this is the only communication.